# Is there an solution to stop looping this

Tags: c, embedded, mplab, proteus

Settings of the MCU:

[image: Settings of the MCU]

This is the circuit in Proteus:

[image: This is the circuit]

I wrote this code for the led to blink for one time only but it's blinking for infinite times.

Could anyone tell how to stop automatically looping this program in Proteus 8 professional simulator?

I've correctly checked and uploaded it to the PIC16F877A MCU.

```
#include<pic.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
__CONFIG(0x3D72);

void delay();

void main()
{
    TRISD=0X00;
    PORTD=0X00;
    RD4=1;
    delay();
    RD4=0;
    delay();
}

void delay()
{
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        __delay_ms(10);
}
```

Comment: Don't use busy-wait delays in the first place - use hardware timers.

Comment: And regarding the update: this isn't how LEDs work, you must limit the current to a fixed value. Otherwise you might damage the MCU and LED both. The MCU pin must be able to source as much current as required.

Answer (score 2):

You have no code that stops `main()` from returning. And many MCU implementations just restart the application if `main()` returns. Your system apparently does this, too, therefore your LED blinks.

The solution is to insert an endless loop at the end of `main()`:

```c
void main()
{
    TRISD=0X00;
    PORTD=0X00;
    RD4=1;
    delay();
    RD4=0;
    delay();

    for (;;) {
        /* do nothing */
    }
}
```